# Regex JavaScript If/Else statement

Tags: javascript, regex

I don't have previous experience working with regex and that's why I need your help.

I have 3 different web services which I'm using to grab data via live search. Here is the logic of my statement which I'm trying to implement.

```
if(carName is entered) {
  getCarName.php?text=blablabla
} elseif (carModel is entered) {
  getCarModel.php?text=blablabla
} elseif (carNumer is entered) {
  getCarNumber.php?text=1337
}
```

The idea is if `carName` is entered it could be a simple string like `Pontiac Firebird 2002`, then `carModel` can be `OHC inline-6 and a single-barrel carburetor`. carName and carModel may contain characters and numbers. `carNumber` can have numbers-only value like `194378`.

I've started evaluation [`regexr.com`](http://www.regexr.com/) website, but still didn't came up with a possible solution to my problem.

I want to have 1 input field (search field). I have different 3 web services. I have a working live search for 1 web service (carName). It's working fine, but I want to make a regex statement to find out when in the input search field is entered carName or carModel or even carNumber. How I can do it?

As an example, here is a code snippet for my live search for carName web service:

```
$('#search').keyup(function() {
        var searchField = $('#search').val();
        var $update = $('#update');

        $.get("getCarName.php?text=" + searchField, function(data) {
          $update.empty();
          var vals = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

            if($.isArray(vals['Car'])) {
              $.each(vals['car'], function(k,v){
                $update.append("<li value='"+v['id']+"'><a href='#'>" + v['car_name'] + "</a></li>");
              });
            } else { 
                $update.append("<li value='"+vals['car']['id']+"'><a href='#'>" + vals['car']['car_name'] + "</a></li>");
            }

        });
      });
```

Based on a code above, I want to create an if/else statement to figure it what which web service it should use based on the input string.

According to the regexr.com carName and carModel can be achieved from:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ 0123456789
```

And carNumber from:

```
0123456789
```

Buy how I can create a If/Else condition according to this?

Can please anyone help me with that?

Comment: `<input type="number" ...>` :)

Comment: Please describe concisely what you're trying to do. Your pseudo-code is IMO incomprehensible.

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is or why you'd even need a regular expression for this.

Comment: It's relatively easy to detect the car number if it's only numbers, but what's the difference between car name and car model? They both seem to contain both letters and numbers.

Comment: Yep, updated a question a bit. How I can create a if/else condition at least based on carNumber?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible suggestion:

1) You can track if input string contains only numbers (means `carNumber` is entered) by only this regex '`[\d]+`'.

2) If input contains not only digits, you can make an array or smth containing all possible car manufacturers names and looking if some word in your input string matches it. If matches, then search by `CarName`

3) If none of above applied - `CarModel` is entered

This is somehow working example

```
var string = 'your input 2014';
var regex = /[\D]+/;

var carsArray = ["Nissan", "Pontiac", "Other one"];
function findInArray(a, s)
{
  for( var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i )
    if( a[i].indexOf( s ) >= 0 )
      return i;
  return -1;
}

if (regex.exec(string)) {
  //there are NOT only numbers     
  if (findInArray(carsArray, string) == '-1') {
    //carModel entered!
  }else{
    //carName entered!
  }
} else {
  //carNumber entered!
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a conditional if/else statement, because I'm looking for the help with it.